# Unknown column in order clause?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm getting the error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'distance' in 'order clause'
```

Here's my query:

```
$place = $place->selectRaw("(3959 * acos(cos(radians(?)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) - radians(?)) + sin(radians(?)) * sin(radians(lat)))) as distance", array($filters['location']['lat'], $filters['location']['lng'], $filters['location']['lat']))
        ->orderBy('distance', 'ASC')
        ->having('distance', '<', 50);
```

For some reason the 'as distance' in the raw select is not being picked up by the order by. What's the solution?

From toSql() I get:

```
"select (3959 * acos(cos(radians(?)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) - radians(?)) + sin(radians(?)) * sin(radians(lat)))) as distance from `products` where `products`.`deleted_at` is null having `distance` < ? order by `distance` asc"
```

Comment: Try using `toSql()` instead of `get()` to get the string representation of the query and see if what's being generated by the Query Builder is what you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks, updated question with response.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: did you try to execute the `sql` which ur get from the `toSql()`? any output from it?

Comment: have you run the query in the SQL?